# MathJax - Loading indicator and hide div until equations are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, loading, mathjax

I try to implement a loading indicator on a page which contains MathJax equations.

While equations are loading, I want to show an indicator loading : I have chosen the following indicator: [spin.js](http://spin.js.org/)

Initially, I just tried by doing:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
          MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "all"} },
          tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']], 
          displayMath: [ ['\\begin{displaymath}','\\end{displaymath}'], ['\\begin{equation}','\\end{equation}'] ],
          processEscapes: true,
          preview: ["[loading...]"],

}});
          </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var opts = {
  lines: 13 // The number of lines to draw
, length: 28 // The length of each line
, width: 14 // The line thickness
, radius: 42 // The radius of the inner circle
, scale: 1 // Scales overall size of the spinner
, corners: 1 // Corner roundness (0..1)
, color: '#000' // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
, opacity: 0.25 // Opacity of the lines
, rotate: 0 // The rotation offset
, direction: 1 // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
, speed: 1 // Rounds per second
, trail: 60 // Afterglow percentage
, fps: 20 // Frames per second when using setTimeout() as a fallback for CSS
, zIndex: 2e9 // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
, className: 'spinner' // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
, top: '50%' // Top position relative to parent
, left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
, shadow: false // Whether to render a shadow
, hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
, position: 'absolute' // Element positioning
};

var target = document.getElementById('hide_page');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
});
```

```
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  //
  //  The document is hidden until MathJax is finished, then
  //   this function runs, making it visible again.
  //
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
    document.getElementById("hide_page").style.visibility = "";
  });
</script>
```

and for the HTML part, I have set :

```
<body>
 <div id="hide_page" style="visibility:hidden">         
  <table>

   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="header_content">
      </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="body_content">
    
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="bottom_content">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>    

    </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

From what I have understood, the function `MathJax.Hub.Queue` is called when all MathJax equations are loaded.

The problem is that I can't get to show the spinner on all the page while MathJax equations are being processed : it appears once equations are loaded but not during loading. I wonder if `$(document).ready(function()` is appropriate in my case because it will be executed once all page (and maybe MathJax equations) is loaded but what do I have to put instead?

The indicator that I use takes as argument a target element into which the spinner is added as first child and horizontally and vertically centered; as you can see above, this is done by putting:

```
var target = document.getElementById('hide_page');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

Unfortunately, the indicator is not displayed while the loading of Mathjax equations.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spinner is in the `hide_page` element, which has `visibility:hidden`, so its contents do not show, including the spinner itself.  Try adding the spinner to the `document.body` instead.  You will also need to stop the spinner once MathJax has finished, so you will need to make the `spinner` variable global and add `spinner.stop()` to the function that you pass to `MathJax.Hub.Queue()`.